# Development environment for Linux wireless using sparse

Tags: kernel, development, c, environment

I am used to using the Eclipse IDE and Visual Studio IDE for development in Java and C#.  I want to modify and compile some files in C using the Linux Wireless subsystem. The site recommends using Sparse but there isn't much documentation regarding it.

Can Sparse be used as a development environment like Eclipse? Is there any documentation regarding this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the context of kernel development, sparse is a tool for checking kernel code, not a development environment. You can read more about sparse at the [sparse homepage](https://sparse.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page).

You may be able to use eclipse for your kernel development environment; as long as you can edit sources and run `make`, any development environment should be fine.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Do you prefer or recommend any environment that helps with say autocomplete?

Comment: I prefer to "keep it simple" and use gvim and a terminal window. vim/gvim has support for completion: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Omni_completion

Comment: Let me try it out

Comment: It's probably going a bit off-topic for this question, so I'd suggest checking out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/149321/what-ide-would-be-good-for-linux-kernel-driver-development .